# Relative Clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

> You must have parents **with whom you can live**

Is the bold part a relative clause? - Relative clauses usually describe the subject, sometimes they are restrictive clauses (essential informations in order to be undestood) or non-restrictive clauses (non-essential information, .i.e.: they aren't necessary to make the sentence understandable).

How would you classify that part? If not a Relative clause, then what?

Comment: Try [this](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm) definition: *Relative clauses are clauses starting with the relative pronouns who**, *that, which, whose, where, when. They are most often used to define or identify the noun that precedes them.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your example "with whom you can live" is a restrictive relative clause (RRC). RRCs with a wh-word begin with a relative expression. Here, the relative expression is "with whom". A relative expression is a NP that is a wh-word, a NP with "whose" as determiner, or a prepositional phrase whose object is a relative expression.